# Laravel validación de fechas

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, validación, date

Tengo dos campos de fecha en un formulario: `fechaInicial` y `fechaFinal`. Los he definido como de tipo `date`.

En el controlador que recibe el formulario he puesto, entre otras reglas de validación, la siguiente:

```
'fechaFinal' => 'required|gte:fechaInicial',
```

Se supone que la validación debería fallar si la `fechaFinal` es anterior a la `fechaInicial`. Sin embargo, no falla. Pasa la validación.

Acaso `gte` no funciona con fechas? Si es así, como debo validar que el final no esté antes del inicio?
Gracias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La regla de validación gte no es para fechas, para eso debes utilizar `after_or_equal`, el cual es exclusivo para fechas.

En tu caso sería algo así:

```
'fechaFinal' => 'required|after_or_equal:fechaInicial',
```

Más información en: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-after-or-equal

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, aunque sólo con las fechas en ISO 8601. Sin embargo, como ese es el formato que usa por defecto, eso no es problema. Gracias, Shaz,

Answer (score 3):

Dejo una segunda alternativa, te puede ser útil si deseas realizar verificaciones mas complejas o personalizadas. Lo que puedes hacer en este caso es hacer uso de [Closures](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#using-closures) incluso puedes personalizar el mensaje a mostrar de acuerdo al error.

El código podría ser algo así:

```
$request->validate([
            'start' => 'required',
            'end' => [
                'required',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
                    if ($value < $request['start']) {
                        $fail($attribute.' no es válido. La fecha final, debe ser posterior a la fecha inicial.');
                    }
                },
```

Comment: ¿Para qué complicar la solución cuando Laravel lo ofrece ya? Esto es como reinventar la rueda.

Comment: "te puede ser útil si deseas realizar verificaciones mas complejas o personalizadas". No creo que el equipo de laravel haya diseñado los closures con la idea de "reinventar la rueda". Tienen sus usos.

Comment: La pregunta es específica, es como ofrecerle un Ferrari para ir a la tienda cuando están preguntando por la bicicleta.